# Is there caching property with argument Instead of cache_proerty in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer like this

```
class PaperEveryoneSerializer(ReadOnlyModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    address = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_author(self, instance):
        if instance.paper_contractors.filter(profile__user=self.context['request'].user).exists():
            return str(instance.author)
        else:
            return ''

    def get_address(self, instance):
        if instance.paper_contractors.filter(profile__user=self.context['request'].user).exists():
            return {"old_address": instance.address.old_address, "old_address_eng": instance.address.old_address_eng}
        address_with_bun = instance.address.old_address.split("-")[0]
        hidden_address = address_with_bun[0:address_with_bun.rindex(" ")]
        old_address_eng = instance.address.old_address_eng
        hidden_address_eng = old_address_eng[old_address_eng.index(" ")+1:len(old_address_eng)]
        return {"old_address": hidden_address, "old_address_eng": hidden_address_eng}
```

I am using this code hiding the private info.
But this code will evaluate two time for `instance.paper_contractors.filter(profile__user=self.context['request'].user).exists()`

Is there way to prevent evaluating two times for queryset?
I am trying to do that with cached property. But it doesn't allow to send arguments.

Comment: You can probably just annotate your instances with the result of `exists()`

Comment: I am almost done with it But I don't know why it shows me duplicate instance in queryset.

 Paper.objects.annotate(is_contractor=Case(When(paper_contractors__profile__user=user), output_field=BooleanField(), default=Value(False)))
<QuerySet [<Paper: Paper object (40)>, <Paper: Paper object (39)>, <Paper: Paper object (37)>, <Paper: Paper object (37)>, <Paper: Paper object (37)>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>

Comment: I looks like it has True False value but I want to save paper_contractors__profile__user matched boolean value only once.

Comment: Try with [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries)

Comment: While we are here, just note that your serializer will now depend on querysets that have this value annotated. You might want to put it as a comment somewhere so others who will work with this will know. Otherwise let's see if someone else here in SO have better ideas to approach this.

Comment: Thanks!
I made it with Exists
It's quiet tough for me :(
Because I am not good at sql query.

Paper.objects.all().annotate(is_contractor=Case(When(Exists(Contractor.objects.filter(paper=OuterRef('pk'), profile__user=self.request.user)), then=True), output_field=BooleanField(), default=Value(False)))

For someone for reference my code.

Comment: @SamKim please don't add your answer to the _question_, there is field below for posting your _answer_, use that. Also you don't need that `Case` etc. you can directly annotate `Exists` and it will give you a boolean.